# In editing mode, all edges are visible through the model, how can I fix it?

Tags: edit-mode

How can I make sure that in the *Edit Mode* in the model the edges are not translucent?

I am in *Solid* mode, I used the *Solidify* modifier

Comment: hello try to switch to opaque mode? shortcut Alt Z